# Split multi-line cells into different rows

Tags: google-apps-script, split, google-sheets, row

I have a script with a function which runs through a range of rows in a Google spreadsheet and splits multi-line cells in column F into multiple rows. It then proceeds to copy down the cells in other columns of the same row to the newly created rows. Following is an example of what I mean.

The range through which the function runs is this:

[image]

The function runs and produces the following:

[image]

As you can see, in the first image, some cells in column F have more than one line. The function detects those, splits them into as many rows as there are line breaks and then copies the remaining cells in the other columns. For both "John Doe" and "Candice Len", column F has multi-line entries and, as such, both of these names got as many rows as addresses in column F after the function ran.

The function I am using is as follows: (column F has index 5 in the function)

```
    function result(range) {
  var output2 = [];
  for(var i=0, iLen=range.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    var s = range[i][5].split("\n");    
    for(var j=0, jLen=s.length; j<jLen; j++) {
      var output1 = []; 
      for(var k=0, kLen=range[0].length; k<kLen; k++) {
        if(k == 5) {
          output1.push(s[j]);
        } else {
          output1.push(range[i][k]);
        }
      }
      output2.push(output1);
    }    
  }
  return output2;
}
```

This is working fine. However, I would like the function to do the same for other columns beyond column F. So, if I have other columns with multi-line entries, I would like the function to run through the rows, split the multi-line cells in as many rows as there are line breaks and copy the content of the cells in the remaining columns to the newly created rows. Below is an example where both column E and F have multi-line entries.

If I have something like this:

[image]

I would want the function to turn it into this:

[image]

In this case, it's important to note that each row would have to have the same number of line breaks for each multi-line cell as the different lines would have to map against the corresponding lines in different columns. In other words, taking the last two screenshots as an example, in the "John Doe" entry, "San Francisco" would have to end up in the same row as "address1" and "Cincinnati" in the same row as "address2". The same for "Washington", "Phoenix", "address1" and "address2", for the "Candice Len" entries.

**Columns E and F are just an example. The script would have to run through multi-line cells ins more than two columns.**

How would I be able to change the script in order for it to be able to do the same for additional columns and not just column F?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this sample script? I think that there are some methods for achieving what you want. So please think of this as one of them. In order to achieve your situation, I separated the script to 3 parts.

### Flow :

1. Parse each cell.

   - This can be seen at `c1` in the script.
2. Create each cell using parsed cells.

   - This can be seen at `c2` in the script.
3. Create output cells.

   - This can be seen at `c3` in the script.

### Sample script :

```
// Main of this script.
function result(range) {
  var output = [];
  for (var i in range) {
    var celLen = 1;
    var c1 = range[i].map(function(e, i){
      var cell = e.toString().split("\n"); // Modified
      var len = cell.length;
      if (len == 1) {
        return cell[0];
      } else if (len > 1) {
        celLen = celLen > len ? celLen : len;
        var t2 = [];
        for (var k=0; k<cell.length; k++) {
          t2.push(cell[k]);
        }
        return t2;
      }
    });
    var c2 = c1.map(function(e, i){
      var r = [];
      if (!Array.isArray(e)) {
        for (var k=0; k<celLen; k++) {
          r.push(e);
        }
      } else {
        for (var k in e) {
          r.push(e[k]);
        }
        if (e.length < celLen) {
          for (var m=0; m<celLen - e.length; m++) {
            r.push("");
          }
        }
      }
      return r;
    });
    var c3 = c2[0].map(function(e, i){return c2.map(function(f, j){return c2[j][i]})});
    Array.prototype.push.apply(output, c3);
  }
  return output;
}

// For testing this script.
function main() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  var r = result(data);
  ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow() + 1, 1, r.length, r[0].length).setValues(r);
}
```

### Sample result :

#### Input :

[image]

#### Output :

[image]

### Note :

- In this sample script, you can increase the columns freely.
- In order to parse each value of cells, `\n` is used.
- I'm not sure about other patterns for your situation. So I prepared this sample script for supposing some situations. Please confirm the sample result.

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thanks you very much for your help!
I have tried running your script and I always get the error: "TypeError: Cannot find function split in object 0. (line 7, file "Split")" back. Any idea of what I may be doing wrong? I have tried changing the "var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();" in the "function main()" to "var data = ss.getActiveRange().getValues();" and then the function runs but only the header on cell A1 is pasted below.

Comment: @franciscofcosta I'm sorry for the inconvenience. In my environment, ``ss.getActiveRange().getValues();`` also works. So can you share a sample sheet with your situation? When there is the sample sheet, it helps to remove the error.

Comment: of course - thank you. You can find the sample sheet here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J_x-fYDnUFKwrYEu9tZz7DRcoP1Rz1KpDTtROoc1WOw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @franciscofcosta Thank you for sharing a sample sheet. Also can I ask you about the range of ``getActiveRange()``? Because I have no information about the range.

Comment: @franciscofcosta I saw your sample sheet. But I couldn't find the cells with multi lines. I cannot access the spreadsheet of ``SpreadsheetApp.openById()``. So I cannot see the sample data. I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, the cells with multilines are in columns L, M and N at the moment

Comment: @franciscofcosta Thank you. I understood it. So should I change from ``SpreadsheetApp.openById()`` to ``SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()``?

Comment: You can, yes. Eventually, I would like a specific sheet to be in the script - that's why I would prefer to use '.openbyid()'

Comment: @franciscofcosta Thank you for replying it. I would like to modify the script. Can you give me a time to do?

Comment: @franciscofcosta I'm sorry for the inconvenience. The reason is that the numbers are included in the cells. So I used ``toString()`` for the error part. I also modified your script. Can you try to run the script again?

Comment: Hi Tanaike, This is working perfectly now!
Thank you very much for your help! (I will award you the bounty as soon as it becomes available to award).

Comment: @franciscofcosta I'm glad your issue was solved. I could also study from your question. Thank you, too.

Comment: @franciscofcosta I'm sorry for the inconvenience. If there are some problems in my answer, please tell me. I would like to study to solve them.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  function result(range) {
  var output2 = [];
  for(var i=0, iLen=range.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    var s = range[i][4].split("\n"); 
    var s1 = range[i][5].split("\n");    
  for(var j=0, jLen=s.length; j<jLen; j++) {
    var output1 = []; 
    for(var k=0, kLen=range[0].length; k<kLen; k++) {
  if(k == 4 ) {
      output1.push(s[j]);
      output1.push(s1[j]); 
      k=k+1
    } 
    else {
      Logger.log(k)
      output1.push(range[i][k]);
    }
  }
  output2.push(output1);
}}
  return output2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ed Nelson. The script works perfectly when I only have two columns with more than one line. How could I change it in order to have 3 or 4 columns with line breaks? Thank you!